# Next.js with next-pwa can't get to _offline page

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-pwa

Trying to make a website + PWA with Next.js + next-pwa.
Installed next-pwa, followed the documentation of this package, specifically 'Offline fallbacks' https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa#offline-fallbacks.
The website becomes installable as PWA, I can install it on PC and phone, but I can't get to _offline page except by manually typing it in url.

next.config.js:

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = withPWA({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    register: true,
    skipWaiting: true
  }
})

module.exports = nextConfig
```

sw.js is automatically generated by next-pwa in public folder.
it has line to include another file, which is also generated by next-pwa:
`importScripts("fallback-development.js");`
fallback-development.js contains:

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
var __webpack_exports__ = {};


self.fallback = async request => {
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestDestination
  switch (request.destination) {
    case 'document':
      if (true) return caches.match("/_offline", {
        ignoreSearch: true
      });

    case 'image':
      if (false) {}

    case 'audio':
      if (false) {}

    case 'video':
      if (false) {}

    case 'font':
      if (false) {}

    case '':
      if (false) {}

    default:
      return Response.error();
  }
};
/******/ })()
;
```

Also tried production build, then fallback-development.js gets another name, and import in sw.js that name is also gets changed to correct one.
In both prod and dev, both locally and with my app deployed to Vercel, I tried to disable network in browser devtools network tab, checked 'disable cache', and checked 'offline' in application-> Service workers.

On PC  in browser console log I don't see any errors related to PWA. I see default browser 'no internet' page if I input some page I haven't visited yet on my website directly in url. On phone, since it's a PWA I can't type in a url like in browser, so it goes back and forth between pages that I switch in navbar with next.js link.

How can I show some 'You are offline' as soon as user's device loses internet access ?